# EF datacontext and entity caching

Tags: entity-framework, caching, garbage-collection

For performance reasons, I cache lots of objects with .NET system.runtime.caching. I'm caching entities coming from a EF datacontext. I'm disposing the datacontext but since the entities coming from it are in the cache, does that mean GC won't be able to collect it?

Example code:

```
 public static Menu GetMenu(string menuName, string languageCode)
        {
            ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
            var menu = (Menu)cache[menuName + "cache"];

            if (menu == null)
            {
                using (PageDb db = new PageDb())
                {
                    menu = db.Menus.Where(m => m.Name == menuName && m.LanguageCode == languageCode).FirstOrDefault();
                }

                CacheItemPolicy policy = new CacheItemPolicy();
                policy.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMonths(1);
                cache.Set(menuName + "cache", menu, policy);
            }

            return menu;
        }
```

As you can see I'm storing a menu object in the cache, but that came from the PageDb datacontext. The menu object is supposed to stay in memory for 1 month, but how about the PageDb datacontext?

Comment: Are you using proxies? They hold a reference to the `ObjectContext`, so could be an issue.

Comment: Yes, I do, I use dbContext to fetch poco classes, some with virtual members in em. So that would mean the dbcontext can't be finalized if the object is cached?